# How can I use one sound to filter another sound?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, filter

Imagine I have two sounds:

Sound A is a very saturated, dynamically high and flat sound. Like a distorted guitar.

Sound B is very dynamically complex, such as a vocal line.

Is there any way for me use the frequencies present in sound B to filter sound A? So if I am singing middle C in Sound B, I will only hear the middle C part of Sound A, and when I stop singing Sound A will become quieter.

Comment: You want to end up with a vocoder?

Comment: Or filter the sound to the frequencies where the voice is most dominant? Sorry for thr double comment :)

Comment: `filter the sound to the frequencies where the voice is most dominant` exactly

Comment: I think a vocoder is what I'm looking for. Make it an answer (:

Comment: are u sure? i was going to answer another thing , cause a vocoder is not *exactly* what we discussed above. But if you looked up vocoders and you are sure it's what you are after , im glad i helped. It's not a "real" answer more of a clarification. :)

Comment: I think @frcake was going to suggest side-chain multi band compression to achieve ducking of some frequencies by another audio track a technique used a lot when mixing

Comment: @DalvOlan yes , except the phase would be flipped so whatever the multiband compressor "cuts" is the only thing from the signal that is left to be heard.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to:

- Convert the pitch of the vocal track into a control signal (CV or CC or some other kind signal).
- Route that control signal to the appropriate controls of the filter.

Some plugins can do this internally. they have a *pitch follower* or *pitch tracking* feature that can use the pitch of a signal to control the plugin's parameters.

Take a look this video from MeldaProduction, about the "Pitch Mode" modulator built into many of their plugins:

Two apologies:

- The the video is kinda complicated. I couldn't easily find a more straightforward one.
- The video shows how to use the pitch of the incoming signal to control the plugin's parameters. You want to use a *different* signal, and the video doesn't show that.

The Melda plugins (and likely most others that have pitch trackers) allow you to use a "sidechain" signal to control some of the parameters. So (using MeldaProduction's MFilter as an example)

- Add MFilter to your distorted guitar track.
- Route the vocal track into the plugin's sidechain.
- Configure a "pitch mode" modulator that follows the sidechain's pitch and controls the frequency and gain of one or more of the filter's frequency bands.

Configuring the pitch tracker to pick out the exact frequencies may or may not be easy to do.

There are probably also separate pitch tracking plugins that can convert pitch into control signals, which you can then connect (using your DAW's routing features) to control a simple filter or EQ plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using logic you do this with the EVOC20 plug-in which is a vocoder.

Comment: Typical we prefer more instructional answers. This one could be improved if you go through the basics of using such a plug-in (the more general and less DAW specific the better!)

Comment: What you are describing sounds like pitch tracking (the voice signal) keying by means of a side-chain detector circuit in a bandpass filter such as a vocoder.